# Functions Date() and today() giving error in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to find the difference in two dates in Julia. However, the functions `Date()` and `today()` are giving errors on executing. On executing the following code line by line,

```
import Dates
origin_date = Date(2000, 01, 01)
today_date = today()   
days_elapsed = today_date - origin_date
```

the following errors occur:

```
julia> import Dates
julia> origin_date = Date(2000, 01, 01)
ERROR: UndefVarError: Date not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
julia> today_date = today()
ERROR: UndefVarError: today not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
julia> days_elapsed = today_date - origin_date
ERROR: UndefVarError: today_date not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `import Dates`, use `Dates.Date()` and `Dates.today()`.

```
julia> import Dates
julia> origin_date = Dates.Date(2000, 01, 01);
julia> today_date = Dates.today();
julia> days_elapsed = today_date - origin_date
7385 days
```

Or instead of using `import Dates`, to use the functions `Date()` and `today()` as they are, first execute `using Dates`.

```
julia> using Dates
julia> origin_date = Date(2000, 01, 01);
julia> today_date = today();
julia> days_elapsed = today_date - origin_date
7385 days
```

More information on dates in Julia can be found here https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/.